# cast an Object[] array to an Integer Array

Tags: c#

What is the easiest way to cast an object array to an integer array?

```
ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
 object arrayObject = al.ToArray(); 
int[]arrayInteger = ?
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `int[]arrayInteger = (int[])al.ToArray(typeof(int));`

But unless you are using .Net 1.1, user a `List<int>` instead.

Comment: I don't see you converting an object[] here.

Answer (score 8):

If you import `System.Linq` namespace you can do this:

```
int[] arrayInteger = a1.Cast<int>().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

(object[] eventTypes) Assuming eventTypes are all objects with integer values, this would do it:

```
        int[] eventTypeIDs = eventTypes.Select( Convert.ToInt32).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Array.ConvertAll`

```
int[] intArray = Array.ConvertAll<object, int>(al.ToArray(), (o) => (int)o);
```

One thing to consider is since this is an `object` array all the values may not be `int`
This is the handy thing about `ConvertAll` as you can add simple conversion logic to catch errors.

Scenario:

```
ArrayList al = new ArrayList() { 1,"hello",3,4,5,6 };
int[] intArray = Array.ConvertAll<object, int>(al.ToArray(), (o) => { int val = -1; return int.TryParse(o.ToString(), out val) ? val : -1;});
```

This way we can perform a `TryParse` on the object to avoid any `InvalidCastException` due to bad data.

Answer (score 1):

or
`int[] intArray = object as int[];`